# Identify insect found in cupboard

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Opening the cupboard I am shocked to find it full of these insects inside. Haven't found them anywhere else. At first, I thought it was ticks, but not so sure. Plan on cleaning out the cupboard and using Bifen I/T to hopefully kill them.

I live in the Caribbean and would like to identify and find out how to get rid of them.

[image: insects]
[image: insects]
[image: insect]

Comment: You should add tag `species-identification`. It can help other people to help you.

Comment: Looks like some sort of [weevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil?wprov=sfti1) to me.

Comment: This is just a rice weevil, *Sitophilus oryzae*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_weevil, or maybe a maize weevil, *Sitophilus zeamais*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I agree. Is there any reason you're posting that as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: Yes, two reasons: first, I was just about to turn off the computer. Second, the user above my comment identified it first, so he deserves the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't have been offended if I had commented "weevil" and you had made your more detailed response an answer. I see a big difference between a quick first impression and a reference to a specific species. :)